# How to route sign_up with Devise while specifying controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to re-route devise's sign_up, but also use my own view for the sign_up page.  I have the following in my routes.rb file:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
  end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations"}
```

But the sign_up page is using the controller "devise/registrations" and displaying the devise view for sign_up.  How do I get it to use the "registrations" controller and display my view?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply generate Devise view and customize it?

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Above command will generate devise views and copy in your view folder.

Comment: I've done this, and have a customized view and a controller for it, registrations_controller.rb . . . . the problem is that when I use devise_scope to change the route, it is no longer using my customized view, but the default devise view instead.